# codeigniter: rest apis with jwt-token, token getting expire during website surfing also

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt, token, rest

**codeigniter: rest apis with jwt-token (algo:HS256), token getting expire during website surfing also.**

Web Application with codeigniter as front-end and CI as back-end. In that jwt-token (expiry time set to 3600) is getting expire after 15mins during website surfing also. I don't know whats wrong with that jwt codeigniter librarry.

In CI controller, my code snippet (token creation):

```
$token_data['id'] = $output->id;
$token_data['firstName'] = $output->firstName;
$token_data['lastName'] = $output->lastName;
$token_data['email'] = $output->email;
$token_data['createdDate'] = $output->createdDate;
$token_data['updatedDate'] = $output->updatedDate;
$token_data['time'] = time();
$user_token = $this->authorization_token->generateToken($token_data);
```

I have implemented temporary solution (not valid) in relevant library:

```
$this->generateToken($token_array);
return ['status' => TRUE, 'data' => $token_decode];
//return ['status' => FALSE, 'message' => 'Token Time Expire.'];
```

But I want proper solution on this issue, if I am surfing web application then how jwt token is getting expire. Please suggest me changes and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not given enough details, how we would know your jwt-token library settings. But code snippet as you provided, it will solve your issue efficiently. Only thing is that user will not get auto logout until he does manually.